# C# DateTime comparer skips from -1 to 1

Tags: c#, datetime, time, compare

Basically I am trying to write an alarm clock for a project (not graded). For some reason, my DateTime comparer skips from -1 to 1 immediately even though the values should be equal.

Is this because it's happening too fast or because I am not using milliseconds?

Here's the snippet of code where I think the problem is (alarmDate is null if it's not set yet):

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTime.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

    if(alarmDate != null)
    {
        int result = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, (DateTime)alarmDate.Value);

        lblTest.Content = alarmDate.Value.ToLongTimeString();
        lblTest2.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

        if(result == 0)
        {
            lblWakeUp.Content = "Wake Up!!!!";
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question or mistake, but I really can't find the answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where are you setting / declaring the `alarmDate` variable..? what is the data `Type` of alarmDate` also do a google search the following `DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,`

Comment: The comparison used compares Ticks which are about 100 nanoseconds each.  Chances are good that your comparison will not ever yield 0.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it's declared as a global variable at the top as

DateTime? alarmDate;

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime` has a precision in reality of about 16 milliseconds, so you have a *very* short window in which two `DateTime`s will be *exactly* equal, and it's very likely that the `DateTime` value you get will *never* equal a specific value.  I would suggest using a flag that is triggered once the time goes past your alarm time:

```
bool alarmTriggered = false;     // <-- new flag
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTime.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

    if(alarmDate != null)
    {
        int result = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, (DateTime)alarmDate.Value);

        lblTest.Content = alarmDate.Value.ToLongTimeString();
        lblTest2.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

        if(result > 0 && !alarmTriggered)   // <-- check flag
        {
            alarmTriggered = true;          // <-- set the flag
            lblWakeUp.Content = "Wake Up!!!!";
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the best way to measure any "passing a value" in anything with a very small precision. +1.

Comment: It worked like you said! Thank you so much :) I will think about it in the future.